# Password requested to install software but no password was placed

Tags: support

I recently got a computer with ubuntu software and for some reason requested a password when I tried to install new software. The problem is, I haven't put in a password and I don't know what to do. Is there any way you can help?

Answer (score 2):

During the Ubuntu installation, you have to enter a password for the user. This password also works as the super user (root) password. However, you can choose to login automatically every time the computer starts, without having to enter the password.

If this is the case and if you didn’t install Ubuntu yourself, and if you can’t get the password set during the installation, you have to manually recover it.
Fortunately, this is very doable. Check this guide on how to recover the root password: https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/393489